# General Solution for $u(r,\theta, t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, bessel-functions

I am trying to find a general solution for the PDE
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\theta^2},$$ using the substitution $u(r,\theta, t)=R(r)S(\theta)T(t).$ The substitution gives the three ODES,
\begin{align}
S''-\beta S&=0 \tag{1}\\
\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+\left(\lambda r+\frac{\beta}{r}\right)R&=0 \tag{2} \\
T'+\lambda T&=0 \tag{3}.
\end{align}
The boundary conditions are $u(1,\theta,t)=0, \forall t>0, \ 0\leq \theta< 2\pi\ $ and $u(r,\theta,0)=f(r,\theta)$, for $0\leq r\leq 1,\ 0 \leq \theta< 2\pi$.

The question states that $\beta=-m^2$, which gives the following solution to $(1)$, $$S_m(\theta)=A_m\cos(m\theta)+B_m\sin(m\theta).$$
The question also states that $\lambda=k^2>0$. By transforming $(2)$ into a Bessel equation of order $m$ $$p\frac{d}{dp}\left(p\frac{dR}{dp}\right)+(p^2-m^2)R=0,$$ we see that this has solution $R_n(r)=J_m(\mu^n_m),$ where $\mu^n_m$ denotes the $n^{th}$ zero of the $m^{th}$ order Bessel function ($R$ is finite as $r\rightarrow 0^+$). Solving $(3)$ gives $$T(t)=C_1e^{-k^2t}.$$ 
But I am unsure if this is correct, as I do not know how to create an infinite series for $u(r,\theta, t)$. I would really appreciate some help, as I have been trying to solve the problem over the last couple of days. Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you unsure on? Also, what are the associated boundary conditions to your PDE? Do you understand how the person got that $\beta = -m^{2}$ and $\lambda = k^{2}$?

Comment: I have just put the boundary conditions in. Thanks for that. I don't quite understand how the power series is formed in this case. I have solved many problems where $$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n(x)Y_n(y),$$ where $X_n(x)$ and $Y_n(y)$ are respective eigenfunctions. But I don't see how this works in our case. For instance, the solution for $T$, is this even with respect to $n$ (e.g. $T_n(t)=..$)?

Comment: You will have a double sum over $k$ and $m$ now i.e $$u(r, \theta, t) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{m \ge 0} \dots$$ Also, it should be $T_{k}(t)$.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense! So the solution is $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0} C_ke^{-k^2t}J_m((\mu^n_m)^2)\left(A_m\cos(m\theta)+B_m\sin(m\theta)\right)?$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry, my double sum above should have been $$\sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{\color{red} n \ge 0} \dots$$ as you have written.

Comment: Do you mean $m$? As $\beta=-m^2$. I think I made a mistake by summing $n$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was correct _originally_ and wrong the second time. The double sum should be over the values of the eigenvalues $k$ and $m$ i.e $$u = \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{\color{green} m \ge 0}$$ not $$u = \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{\color{red} n \ge 0}$$

Comment: I also wish to find the formula Fourier-Bessel coefficients when $f(r,\theta)=1$. Should I create a new post? I believe I have found them.

Comment: It would be appropriate to make a new post for that question.

Comment: Sure. It would be great if someone could post a verification to this problem so I could make my first accepted response.

Comment: @Betty, you can ask Mattos to post an answer, or post an answer yourself. If you want to send a message to Mattos simply include "@Mattos" in your comment.

Comment: @Mattos could you kindly post an answer :)